# Can we change "Send to Messenger" plugin button text?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-send-api

I want to change button text which is generated by "Send to Messenger" plugin using javascript facebook SDK.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: can i do something with jQuery when the button gets loaded in browser.

Comment: One more question i need to ask. Can i change font family or font size from fb send api to end user.. is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, you can change the button texts! Unfortunately, you can't use arbitrary text. You can only choose from the pre-defined button texts by [facebook.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin#approved-CTA)

Here's the list of button texts that you can use

- GET_THIS_IN_MESSENGER
- RECEIVE_THIS_IN_MESSENGER
- SEND_THIS_TO_ME
- GET_CUSTOMER_ASSISTANCE
- GET_CUSTOMER_SERVICE
- GET_SUPPORT
- LET_US_CHAT
- SEND_ME_MESSAGES
- ALERT_ME_IN_MESSENGER
- SEND_ME_UPDATES
- MESSAGE_ME
- LET_ME_KNOW
- KEEP_ME_UPDATED
- TELL_ME_MORE
- SUBSCRIBE_IN_MESSENGER
- SUBSCRIBE_TO_UPDATES
- GET_MESSAGES
- SUBSCRIBE
- GET_STARTED_IN_MESSENGER
- LEARN_MORE_IN_MESSENGER
- GET_STARTED

You can change the text by setting **cta_text** attribute to one of the preceding
options. In this example, I used **KEEP_ME_UPDATED** option:

```
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
  cta_text="KEEP_ME_UPDATED"
  messenger_app_id="<APP_ID>" 
  page_id="PAGE_ID" 
  data-ref="<PASS_THROUGH_PARAM>" 
  color="<blue | white>" 
  size="<standard | large | xlarge>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to do it is by placing the send-to-messenger div inside another div & formatting the parent div & a sibling div.
The trick is to pass the click event through an element.
This requires position first div as absolute.
Here's my code

```
<div style='height: 32px;width: 148px;display: inline-block;overflow: hidden;color: #fff;'>
   <div style='background-color: #5ac7ec;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:148px;z-index:2;line-height:36px;>
     CONNECT
   </div>
   <div class="fb-send-to-messenger"
      messenger_app_id="123456789"
      page_id="987654321"
      data-ref="some_data"
      color="blue"
      size="large">
   </div>
```

Comment: Is it so hard to format your answer? This is terrible. 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cta_text` option but you cannot write anything there, only couple of predefined texts.

- [Read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin/)